# bind click handler to body only after click on element

Tags: jquery

i have a very conceptual question regarding jquery. i have this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/zvCrN/

What i want to do is:
bind a click handler to the link. 
click on the link to display an alert. 
Only after this has happened, bind a click event handler to body, so that clicks anywhere in the body display a different alert.

I'm sure it's trivial, i just can't wrap my head around it. How can i bind the handler to body so it doesn't trigger on the link click as well?

Any help appreciated,

Comment: I'm not sure of what's blocking you. Is that the propagation ? If so add `event.stopPropagation()` in the click handler of the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#infolink").click(function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    alert('link')
});

$('body, :not("#infolink")').click(function() {
    alert('body');
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zvCrN/3/)**

Comment: your example has pushed me in the right direction. http://jsfiddle.net/shQVC/ . But i was hoping that there is a more elegant solution to show this causality than using boolean semaphores.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
var link = $('#infolink');
var handler = function (event) {
  link.off('click', handler);
  event.stopPropagation();
  $('body').on('click', function (event) {
    alert('some other message');
  });
  alert('some message');
};
link.on('click', handler);
```

Comment: you code does exactly what mine does. i want the body alert to happen ONLY IF the link has already happened.

Comment: @glasspill In my example the handler is only attached to the body in the click event of `#infolink`. This gives the behaviour you requested.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but i think i need to rephrase my issue: i do not want the body alert to trigger on the first link click.